# MySQL Connector Classpath

Tags: java, mysql, linux, jdbc

my $CLASSPATH skills are not too great and I am having trouble setting up mysql-connector to use my MySQLAccess class.  I compiled and put MySQLAccess class inside the same directory as my-sql-connector.jar  Here is my code:

```
java -classpath :/home/rick/Downloads/mysql-connector-java-5.1.22/mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar MySQLAccess

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MySQLAccess
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MySQLAccess
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: MySQLAccess. Program will exit.
```

Comment: btw **Unrelated:** Why classpath starts with colon? I mean a _colon_ on *nix systems and _semicolon_ on Windows are used to separate paths, but you for some reason begin with it. Just strange ...

Comment: If MySQLAccess is something you wrote, @user1825110, then the other answer will sort you. Else, edit your question adding MySQLAccess.java and what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

put a `.` that indicate current location also

```
java -classpath /home/rick/Downloads/mysql-connector-java-5.1.22/mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar:. MySQLAccess
```